# Live reload/refresh solution for HTML/CSS in 2017

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, browser-sync

So it's 2017 and whilst coding websites we still have to edit, save, switch windows, then hit refresh. Make a small change and do it all over again. And again. And again etc etc.

Am I missing something because surely there is a solution for this now whereby the browser can update automatically as we type, or at least instantly as we hit save?

[jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) is a perfect working example of what I'm looking for on my local Apache (Windows 10) setup. I've tried various methods including [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) and [LiveJS](http://livejs.com/) but they are too long-winded and often there's a lag of around 2-4 seconds which is just not quick enough when building websites. They also require a browser extension or a snippet of code inserted into every page that requires monitoring. It all just seems very "hacky" and very 1990's.

I'm curious as to how other developers handle this problem? Is there now a NodeJS solution that I've not come across or is everyone else just doing the edit, save, switch, refresh method? Surely not? For reference I use Atom to edit my html/css/js files etc, then save and view the changes in Chrome. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Hugely appreciated actually.

Comment: Most webpack templates do this (so technically this is a node solution). Hot replacement for JS is hit-or-miss but live-updating CSS is instant and reliable. Like [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

Comment: If you're just doing html, css, and js I wouls recommend brackets.io. It has a live preview feature that updates every time there's a change, and it's also open source.

Comment: insert `meta` tag [<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

Comment: Thank you @RBCunhaDesign for pointing me towards Brackets! I've just downloaded it and first impressions seem very promising. I've already got the Live Preview mode working with a test html file and it seems lightning fast when reloading — almost instant. Welcome to 2017! :)

Comment: @BenClarke , this is more like 2012. You may not understand it yet, but what you need is a task-runner. See my answer for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but if I'm honest I have no idea what a webpack is. I've just Googled it but initial search results all point to GitHub where there's no real explanation of what a webpack does? Would you mind giving me a very brief explanation of what it is and how I can use it to solve my original question? Many thanks.

Comment: @BenClarke I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @BenClarke the best place to read about it is [here](https://webpack.js.org/) - its purpose is to take several files, some of which may not be browser compatible (e.g. SASS, ES6), and bundle it into a file browsers can load. Usually this includes minifying and so forth. People have extended this tool (and its [dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)) to do things like hot-reloading styles without refreshing the page.

Comment: Okay so I'm a few days in now and Brackets has been a real gem of a find. I especially love how it changes the CSS in the browser as you're typing — no save or refresh required! My question now is can browsersync do this? I've got browsersync running and working (proxy mode on localhost) but it requires a file save to inject the CSS — no live updating as you type :( Is this at all possible with browsersync or do all files need saving? Many thanks again

Answer (score 19):

***EDIT** (3/25/2022)*

I would just use the Create React App: https://create-react-app.dev/

Or I have created and use a modified and stripped down version of the Create React App template here: https://github.com/stefanbobrowski/Template that also includes a hooked up react-router, useContext global state, and scss.

---

I dropped gulp and now just use npm scripts https://www.npmjs.com/

Right in the `package.json` file you can use SCSS, autoprefix it, uglify and minify it and your scripts, and control which folders it will output to, for example a production folder.

Here is a sample setup in `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "Sample build",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "New build",
    "author": "Stefan Bobrowski",
    "license": "MIT",
    "main": "index.html",
    "scripts": {
        "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r production/css/*.css",
        "scss": "node-sass --output-style expanded --indent-width 4 -o production/css development/scss",
        "uglify": "uglifyjs development/js/*.js -m -o production/js/scripts.js",
        "serve": "browser-sync start --server --files \"production/css/*.css, production/js/*.js\"",
        "build:css": "npm run scss && npm run autoprefixer",
        "build:js": "npm run uglify",
        "build:all": "npm run build:css && npm run build:js",
        "watch:css": "onchange \"development/scss\" -- npm run build:css",
        "watch:js": "onchange \"development/js\" -- npm run build:js",
        "watch:all": "npm-run-all -p serve watch:css watch:js",
        "start": "npm run build:all && npm run watch:all"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "postcss-cli": "^3.0.0-beta",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.7.6",
        "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
        "onchange": "^3.2.1",
        "uglify-js": "^2.8.3"
    }
}
```

And corresponding file structure setup:

```
Project
|__ development
|       |____ js
|       |____ scss
|
|__ production
|        |___ js
|        |___ css
|        |___ images
|
|_ index.html
|_ package.json
```

All the developer has to do is run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: This is amazing. Just implemented a version of it a bit modernised but the core is there. Great answer

Comment: @tpinto Thanks It has worked wonders for me in the past. You're right I should probably update this with more modern packages etc.

Comment: Now in 2019 I would recommend Parcel bundler. With no configuration it handles bundling your different files types like SCSS, a dev server, hot reloading, etc. Check out this repo for a simple setup: https://github.com/stefanbobrowski/ReactHooksParcel

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** `live-server` hasn't been updated since Nov 26, 2018.

---

[live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) and [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).

Live-server able you to instant wrap your application under web server (nodejs) and live-reload all sources to your browser (through webSocket).

Just type `$> live-server` in your project folder and it works!

You can use this in couple with json-server, who give you a very dead simple way to create CRUD REST APIs, with json keys and values, from JSON file.

Provide a .json file with the DB Schemas, in a json format, just type $> `json-server --watch mydb.json` and it works fine too!

2 minutes of your time gives you a web-server with live-reload capabilities and a custom decentralized API.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Live-server seems great for html/css, but it won't open my php index file? From reading the GitHub page I think it's html/css/js only. Which is a shame because it was such a breeze to set up, and worked well with html/css. So close to perfect! :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: Live Preview, VSCode extension by Microsoft: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server

Answer (score 1):

Using a **[task-runner](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/harness-machines-productive-task-runners/)** is absolutely fundamental for every self-respecting developer.

In my opinion, your best bet is to set-up a **[Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)**, paired with **[Browser-Sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync)** for your project. It can be set to listen for changes in every type of file that you are using, minimizing the hassle of guessing what is changed and what is not.

You can find a neat tutorial on how to do this **[here on CSS Tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)**

**[UPDATE 12/17/2019]**:

A better approach would be to use live-reload is by using an npm plugin called **[live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)**.

You just open the parent directory of your project e.g. `parent-dir/` where your project lies e.g. `parent-dir/project`. Then, you open up a terminal and type in:

```
live-server project
```

Hit Enter, and your project will be opened up in your default browser window.

> **NOTE:** You will need **[nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)** if you plan on using **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)**.

Comment: This is not necessarily a bad answer but a bit out of date already.

Comment: @DaveKanter , duely noted.

Comment: "absolutely fundamental for every self-respecting developer."

A task runner is a tool, and it doesn't suit all workflows. Self respect does not come from picking and using tools that are trendy.